# Laravel 10 error : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: laravel, request, cors

i'm trying to recieve some data from a http post request with laravel  and i'm getting this
error  Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
does anybody know how to solve this?

i checked the manual but all it says is that cors is pre installed but not how to use it

i also checked the corse config file it looks like this:

```
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

];

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Answer (score 0):

Open the `config/cors.php` file and set the appropriate configuration. For example, to allow requests from any origin you can set:

```php
'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
```

In production is better to specify the allowed origins.

Comment: thanks for your help my corse file looks like this:


    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,

];

but still get the error

Comment: Try to change _allowed_methods_ and _allowed_origins_ values from `['']` to `['*']`